# Spring AMQP - Detect rejected messages?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Is there a way in Spring AMQP to detect when a consumer has rejected a message?

My application declares the exchange, but the consumer declares the queue. I know that the consumer can set a dead letter exchange, but I want to remove this responsibility from the consumer. I need to somehow be notified that a consumer has rejected a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I need to know"

I assume you mean the code that sent the message.

No; there is no such mechanism; the producer and consumer are independent.